# Dividing numbers between rows in MySQL + PHP

Tags: php, mysql, arrays

Hi I am working on a kind of raffle system which divides 1 million random numbers into an x amount of tickets, e.g. 1 million random numbers to 10,000 tickets.

Each ticket is a row in a database, we then have another table ticket numbers in which i need to give 100 numbers to each ticket they are related by the ticket id.

So at the moment this is my code:

```
//Amount of the 1 million tickets divided to the tickets
$numbersPerTickets = $_POST['numbersPerTicket'];

//The total cost of the property
$propertyPrice = $_POST['propertyPrice'];

//The total amount of tickets
$totalTickets = NUMBER_CIELING / $numbersPerTickets;

//The ticket price
$ticketPrice = $propertyPrice / $totalTickets;

//Generate array with random numbers up to 999,999
$randomTicketNumbers = createTicketNumbers();

//Creation loop counter
$ticketCreationCount = 1;

//Loop and create each ticket
while($ticketCreationCount <= $totalTickets)
{

    //Create a padded ticket number
    $ticketNumber = str_pad($ticketCreationCount, 6, 0, STR_PAD_LEFT);

    $query = '
        INSERT INTO tickets(
            propertyID,
            ticketNumber,
            price
        )
        VALUES(
            "'.$propertyID.'",
            "'.$ticketNumber.'",
            "'.$ticketPrice.'"
        )
    ';

    $db->query($query);

    //Get the ID of the inserted ticket to use to insert the ticket numbers
    $ticketID = $db->insert_id;

    $loopBreak = $numbersPerTickets;
    $addedNumberCount = 1;

    foreach($randomTicketNumbers as $key => $value)
    {

        $query = '
            INSERT INTO ticketNumbers(
                ticketID,
                number
            )
            VALUES(
                "'.$ticketID.'",
                "'.$value.'"
            )
        ';

        $db->query($query);

        unset($randomTicketNumbers[$key]);

        if($addedNumberCount == $loopBreak){ 
            break;
        }else{ 
            $addedNumberCount++;
        }

    }

    $ticketCreationCount++;

}
```

But this isn't working it adds the right amount of tickets, which in the case for testing is 10,000 but then adds far too many ticket numbers, it ends up exceeding the million numbers in the random tickets array, The random tickets array is just a simple 1 tier array with 1 million numbers sorted randomly.

Comment: I'm not a php guy, but can you use a `for` instead of `while` to limit the loop to 10,000 ?

Comment: @ChrisGessler Hi Chris, The first loop is running fine and is limited the the number of tickets, it's the second loop in which the numbers are being added to the tickets which is giving an unexpected result, I just can't see why there are too many tickets being added...

Comment: I guess I don't understand, you say the right amount of tickets, then say far too many tickets...  Anyway, I'd get rid of the while loop and the foreach loop and replace with for loops.

Comment: Sorry! I keep forgetting, the ticket amount is correct, it's the numbers that get added to the tickets that is wrong, have amended the question

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Change the foreach loop to for:

```
for ($i = 1; $i <= $numbersPerTickets; $i++) {
    $query = ' 
        INSERT INTO ticketNumbers( 
            ticketID, 
            number 
        ) 
        VALUES( 
            "'.$ticketID.'", 
            "'.$randomTicketNumbers[$i].'" 
        ) 
    ';
```

Guaranteed to only give you $numbersPerTickets iterations and removes the complexity of the iterator++/break logic.

Sometimes simple is better.

Please correct my php!  TIA.

Comment: Going to give it a go, need to empty out my inserted tests, millions of rows :S